# Bootstrap 3 tooltip doesn't follow when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have tooltips with Bootstrap (3) and attached them to the body as they would otherwise appear below other elements. However, I guess, since I use that configuration now they don't follow when the user scroll the page. Instead they are shown in the original position of the page.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

This is my configuration:

```
container: 'body',
placement: 'auto top',
viewport: 'body'
```

I can see that the more i scroll the less distance to the top is applied to the element. For instance initially 420px to the top, scroll down a bit and now it's 350px

Comment: Did you tried using `$('#element').tooltip('update')` on your data change.?

Comment: I just get an error, but I don't see it as a method in the docs either?

Comment: A quick fix could be to set window.pageYOffset = 0 everytime something resizes, but I guess that would have some drawbacks.

Comment: Every plugin needs to be destroyed and re initialized after a new data enters a page. I think this might be your problem. you should destroy the tooltip plugin and recall it after the data has entered the page and check.